# Compiling linux kernel module, KBUILD_CFLAGS in makefile does not work

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, compiler-flags

I run the `make` file with adding below line in the Makefile.

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS += -DXFLAGS
```

In my .c file I have:

```
#ifdef XFLAGS
printk(...);
#endif
```

The make compilation is successful, however, I am not able to see the message in the log files like `/var/log/syslog`.
I'm wondering to know what can cause this problem? (the flags can not be set)
Note that inside the printk has no problem. As I commented the `#ifdef` and the printk works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a new variable assignment to the makefile doesn't do anything.  You have to *use* that variable in the compiler invocation.  You don't show the compile rule in your makefile or the compile command that make prints out, so there's not much more we can say.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to it. Can you please explain more what you mean? I have not used the `KBUILD_CFLAGS` anywhere else. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is really a question specifically about the Linux kernel build environment: it's not related to make or the compiler at all.  You'll probably have more luck asking on the Unix & Linux site, or at least modifing the tags on your question.  However, from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt it seems to depend on whether you're building a module vs. not, etc.  I am not very familiar with the details of modifying the Linux kernel to add flags like this so there's not much more help I can give.